# Search data for match in two files then select record and write to third file

Tags: python-3.x

Using Python 3 to load two files then use file A data to find the record in file B then write that record to file C.

First step I'm trying to do open the files A & B, do a search for a match, then just write the match to file C however it's not generating any output.

```
fileA = open('C:\\tmp\\somefile.csv', 'r')
fileB = open('C:\\tmp\\somefile.txt', 'r')
fileC = open('C:\\tmp\\somefile.txt', 'w')

for line1 in fileA:
    for line1 in fileB:
        if line1 == line1:
            fileC.write("%s\n" %(line1))
```

Once I start generating the matching strings from fileA & fileB to fileC I can then work on selecting the record from fileB and write it to fileC

Comment: Did you tried `fileA.read() == fileB.read()`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use .read() method and if you wantto match beetwen lines you can split them:

```
fileA = open('C:\\tmp\\somefile.csv', 'r')
fileB = open('C:\\tmp\\somefile.txt', 'r')
fileC = open('C:\\tmp\\somefile.txt', 'w')

#if you looking for char level match delete .split('\n') 's
for line1 in fileA.read().split('\n'):
    for line12 in fileB.read().split('\n'):
        if line1 and line1 == line2: #your if statement wrong correct it
            fileC.write("%s\n" %(line1))
```

edit: added line1 to if statement for checking empty lines.

Comment: When I adjusted my code to match the above it only returned one column of 3k blank spaces  


1.) File A contains one column of 3k email addresses.  


2.) I need to take each email entry in File A and search File B for the email address line by line.   


3.) Once I find the email address I need to write the entire line in File B to File C

Comment: than you have lot of blank lines with changing if statement you can correct it like: "if line1 and line1==line2:"

Answer (score 0):

You need to read all lines of the file via readlines(), and then compare as follows

```
fileA = open('C:\\tmp\\somefile.csv', 'r')
fileB = open('C:\\tmp\\somefile.txt', 'r')
fileC = open('C:\\tmp\\somefile.txt', 'w')

#Read all lines in the files
linesA = fileA.readlines()
linesB = fileB.readlines()

#Iterate through the lines
for line1 in linesA:
    for line2 in linesB:
        if line1 and line2: #Check for empty lines
            if line1 == line2: #If lines match, write them to fileC
                fileC.write("%s\n" %(line1))
```